# How to replicate a folder structure

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I want to be able to replicate only the folder structure (not the contents) from one location to another in c# 3.5

for example
C:\Some Folder
    + Folder A
        + Sub Folder A
        + Sub Folder B
           + Sub Folder B1
            + Sub Folder B2
      + Sub Folder C

To New Location
C:\Some New folder
   + Folder A
     + Sub Folder A
etc... etc..

Comment: A: What have you tried. B: What are you having trouble with.  I would like to see rainbows everyday but no one makes them for me.  Please See the fac http://stackoverflow.com/faq for how to write a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to create the same files, but not the contents within the same structure.

Something like this might work:

```
public static TotallyNotRecursiveAndCreateDirs(string root, string newRoot)
    {
        DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetPathRoot(root)); 
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach(DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir.FullName.Replace(root, newRoot));
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach(FileInfo file in files)
            {
                File.Create(file.FullName.Replace(root, newRoot));
            }
        }
    }
```

You might also want to do some exception checking to ensure that the root and the newRoot parameters are valid (ie: rooted, etc...)

If you don't want the files and just the directories, then just remove the second loop.

Comment: I'm not seeing any recursion in `RecurseAndCreateDirs`.

Comment: rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) is a recursive call under the hood I believe. I was totally planning on writing my own recursive call, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tested the code and it works.. I was looking at a recursive way of achieving the same result however the trick in your solution was to use dir.FullName.Replace(root, newRoot) which is the one that replicates the folder structure from the root to the new root.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a folder structure at `src` to `dest`:

1. Create `dest`.
2. (Optional) Set permissions on `dest` to match `src`.
3. For each folder `name` in `src`, copy the folder structure at `src\name` to `dest\name`.